# Looking for cloud function alternatives - Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture, google-cloud-functions, microservices, scalability

everybody,

We're working on a project for university. The project should run in the cloud and be highly scalable. We outsourced all functions to Google Cloud Functions, which works great. Now we're looking for alternative implementations that work even better for our use case or can scale better.

That's why we're looking for some different approaches to solve this use case: 
It's a web scraper where many parallel requests from different users go to that system. The system then scrapes the data parallel from different websites and parses the content. Subsequently, the results are reassembled and sent back to the users. What I've described here as "the system" is a huge collection of cloud functions/ micro services which are doing their part.

I have no experience with Kafka, but we have thought about using stream processing. Are there other frameworks that we should consider? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Kafka is closer to PubSub, not Functions

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you are describing you should check:

1. [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/)
2. [Google Kuberneted Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/)
3. [Google Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/)

All 3 products should be okay for your use-case but each having its own pros/cons.

Once you read through the description of each one and/or watch the intro videos, you should be able to determine which one is the best for you.

Comment: Those aren't quite the same as FaaS. As commented, PubSub calling a Cloud Function would ultimately scale better

Comment: Reading again the details of the question, I believe what you say makes sense. However, keep in mind that Cloud Functions have multiple limits and quotas that might be a problem in the end of the day. So possibly it will need a few tricks to make it work with PubSub and either cloud Functions or an alternative.